# How to resolve exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; in java

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

In my code `query` is working fine but at the time of iteration it throws this error.

My code here:

```
Session session = null;
try{
    Query qu=session.createSQLQuery("select plot_no from house_details where type='duplex'");
    List<Long> li =  qu.list();
    System.out.println("---li---"+li.toString());
    for (Iterator itr = li.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        String plotNo = itr.next().toString();

        if(plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601"){
            System.out.println("---if---");
            //code here
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("---else---");
            Query qu1 = session.createSQLQuery("select distinct name,houseno from house_details");
            List li1 =  qu1.list();
            for (Iterator itr1 = li.iterator(); itr1.hasNext();) {
                Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr1.next();
                String houseName = (String) obj[0];
                String houseNo = (String) obj[1];
                System.out.println("---houseName--->"+houseName);
            }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();

}finally {
   if(session!=null){
    session.close();
   }
}
```

**output:**

```
---li---[501, 0, 101, 101, 114]
---else---
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

it shows error in `Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr1.next();` line.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the cast: you are treating an iterator over the list `li` as if it were an iterator over a list of arrays, while in fact it is an iterator over a list of `BigDecimal`s. It's `li1` that you should be iterating:

```
for (Iterator itr1 = li1.iterator() ; itr1.hasNext() ; )
//                     ^
```

Another error happens early on:

```
List<Long> li =  qu.list();
```

it should be

```
List<BigDecimal> li =  qu.list();
```

because objects inside the list returned by your query are of type `BigDecimal`, as confirmed by the failing cast.

Comment: i'm got **101** two times, it is going in **else** loop also two times,how to stop it i want only one time is enough.

Comment: @Sri `select distinct plot_no` in the first query should do the trick then.

Comment: Thank You it's working fine but some scenarios i got **501, 520, 601** values these are checking in **if ** condition,so **if** loop executing three time, in this scenario any possibility for execute **if** condition only one time

Comment: @Sri Add a `boolean enteredIf` variable *before* the loop, and set it to `false`. Change your condition to `if (!enteredIf && (plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601")))`, and set `enteredIf` to `true` inside the conditional. This way you'd process `if` only once, and all other times you'd be going to the `else` branch.

Comment: i write **boolean enteredIf=false; if (!enteredIf && (plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601"))){ enteredIf=true; //my code }** this process is correct? but no change in my **output**

Comment: @Sri `boolean enteredIf=false;` goes before the `for` loop, not before the `if`.

Comment: No change  @dasblinkenlight i added before **for** loop

Answer (score 1):

As the error says: a single BigDecimal cannot be cast to an Object-Array. 
You have the wrong list to iterate over: li <> li1.
Change `for (Iterator itr1 = li.iterator(); itr1.hasNext();) {` to for `(Iterator itr1 = li1.iterator(); itr1.hasNext();) {` and then it should work.

Comment: i'm got **101** two times, it is going in **else** loop also two times,how to stop it i want only one time is enough

Comment: Add a "distinct" to your first query. Like `select distinct plot_no from...`

Comment: some scenarios i got 501, 520, 601 values these are checking in **if ** condition,so **if** loop executing three time, in this scenario any possibility for execute **if** condition only one time